# Illegal character in opaque part when Packing a war

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to build an Spring Boot-Application with JSF andd an embedded Tomcat.

I would like to get an .war-File. In Eclipse the Application is running fine but if I start the .war I get following Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 135: jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5
.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 135: jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/
faces-config.xml
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:764)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:353)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 135: jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:751)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 135: jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
        at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:137)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1362)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1331)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:742)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 135: jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
        at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.loadURLs(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:110)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 135: jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.loadURLs(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:164)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

My **POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>OrgTool</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.oracle.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3m</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6-rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I solve this Issue?

Comment: the `^` character after war in the path seems suspicious in `...0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF....`

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Yes. I think this is the Issue, but I don't know why this happens or how to fix it.

Comment: first naif thing I would try: via eclipse, crtl+h > File Search and scan your project for that character if ever in any conf file there was a typo or unwanted character

Comment: @A.DiMatteo The search returns 0 results. So no, there isn't any Conf-File with this char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. Shame on me for that.

I only had to update my Maven...

Comment: What update did you make to resolve this error? Can you please update this? This statement does not help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error as well, the key is to look at that message and count the characters to reach the index, which in your case is 135 (You'd left that out of your post but I see it in the log).

The 135th character of "jar:war:file:/D:/Eigene%20Dokumente/Projekte/Abschlussprojekt/workspace/OrgTool-Sommerfest/target/OrgTool-Sommerfest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war^/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml" is "^" (right inbetween "SNAPSHOT.war" and "/WEB-INF")

In my case, the illegal character was a space in a file path.